# How do I install android SDK using SDK tools-version 26.1.1

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager, android-tools-namespace

I just wanted to install Android SDK for Appium setup and grid test. But i did not find the SDK tools version 24.1.1. So I had to download 26.1.1 (windows) version and in this version, I am not able to find the sdkmanager.exe instead I got sdkmanager.bat (but i don't know how to do the installation with this .bat(batch) file).Kindly help.

Comment: I would suggest you to install complete Android Studio which will install everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

Either you use Android Studio to get a UI in which you can easily download whatever version you prefer. Or you simply open `cmd` and run a list of commands

1. Open a Command Prompt in the location of the `sdkmanager.bat`
2. Run `sdkmanager.bat --update` to update the list
3. Run `sdkmanager.bat --list` to show two lists, first one is any installed package (is usually not present if you haven't got any packages installed) and a second list containing all available packages
4. Check the list and find the appropiate platform and packages you want

---

I recommend the correct **build-tools** for a **platform** of your choice and the **platform-tools** e.g.

1. `sdkmanager.bat --install plaform-tools`
2. `sdkmanager.bat --install platforms;android-26`
3. `sdkmanager.bat --install build-tools`